# React Navigation Drawer Navigation to navigate a specific screen but with different logic

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

In my app, I have 5 screens and in each 5 screen, I need to render 2 same component + other components. So, what I want is, that when user clicked "Dashboard" on Drawer navigation, I want him to navigate Dashboard screen with my 2 component + dashboard components. If the user clicked "Location" screen, I also want to render 2 component + Location components. How can I achieve this? I don't want to copy paste 2 component all over the place, because, in those components I determine a time range, that causes page to re-render. So, I don't want user to select this date, in all the pages that he visits, plus I don't want to copy paste the 200line code to all 5 screens.

in index.android.js I have:

```
const MyDrawerNavigation = DrawerNavigator({  
  Dashboard: { screen: Dashboard },
  Location: {screen: Location},
//other 3 screens are here too.
);
```

I hope, I could tell my question good enough. If anything is unclear to you, I can give more information.

Comment: You can call component in other component.

Comment: No, I know I can call component. However, that is not the case. I set date information to the state on a page. The page renders according to that state. If I call that component, It'll automatically come with the default dates, no matter what the user did on the previous page to set the date. If I can store those dates in the async store before they leave the page, I can call those components. Since they are drawer navigations, how can I store that information, after the user left that screen?